# Sequence of integers without 3-terms AP in it.

Tags: combinatorics, word-problem

> In a school there are $2023$ students, numbered $1$ to $2023$. The teacher met the students one by one in the order of their numbers, and gave a candy to each student except if that would mean three students whose numbers form an arithmetic sequence all got candies. In this way, the teacher would give a candy to students 1 and 2, but not student 3 (as 1, 2, 3 form an arithmetic sequence), then to students 4 and 5, but not to students 6 and 7 (as both 4, 5, 6 and 1, 4, 7 are arithmetic sequences), and so on. How many students got candies in the end?

I tried to list the number and found the number 1,2,4,5,10,11,13,14,28,29,31,32,37,38,40,41 is available In the first 50 numbers. The thing I could only found is that everytime it start getting a candy, it would be in the form of ✅✅❌✅✅ (for example: In number 10,11,12,13,14, 12 is not available)

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: I tried to find the first 50 numbers the see is there any sequence but there is not, I wanna know is there a fast way to calculate it

Comment: In addition to lacking any context or evidence of your own efforts, putting "help quick please" in the title is a dead giveaway that you're trying to get someone to help you with course work or an ongoing contest. Neither of those is what this site is for.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I have already written what I have done and changed the title. Sorry about the frustration I have made to you but this is my first time to post questions here so I may not understand the rules

Comment: arithmetic sequence is $u_{n+1} = \lambda + u_n$ su $u_n = u_0 + n \lambda$? this seems very restrictive

Comment: Hint: look base 3

Comment: Thanks Bro I know the way to calculate it, I tell the answer when I finish

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace your title "An interesting counting question" which is un-informative into one that can be retrieved by further searches. Do you agree ?

Comment: Thanks for your changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I programmed the thing supposing you don't want $3$ consecutive elements of your list to be in an arithmetic sequence, i.e. for $p<q<r$ in your list, $q-p \neq r-q$, here is the list I obtained:
$$[1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 13, 14, 28, 29, 31, 32, 37, 38, 40, 41, 82, 83, 85, 86, 91, 92, 94, 95, 109, 110, 112, 113, 118, 119, 121, 122, 244, 245, 247, 248, 253, 254, 256, 257, 271, 272, 274, 275, 280, 281, 283, 284, 325, 326, 328, 329, 334, 335, 337, 338, 352, 353, 355, 356, 361, 362, 364, 365, 730, 731, 733, 734, 739, 740, 742, 743, 757, 758, 760, 761, 766, 767, 769, 770, 811, 812, 814, 815, 820, 821, 823, 824, 838, 839, 841, 842, 847, 848, 850, 851, 973, 974, 976, 977, 982, 983, 985, 986, 1000, 1001, 1003, 1004, 1009, 1010, 1012, 1013, 1054, 1055, 1057, 1058, 1063, 1064, 1066, 1067, 1081, 1082, 1084, 1085, 1090, 1091, 1093, 1094]$$

I double checked it with a verification function. Its length is $128$

Here is my codeine python:

```
def next_arithmetics (lis):
    n = len(lis)
    nex = []
    maxi = lis[n-1]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            p = 2*lis[i] - lis [j]
            if p > maxi and not(p in nex):
                nex.append(p)
    nex.sort()
    return nex
```

```
def non_arithmetics (n):
    lis = [1,2]
    mini = 3
    while mini <= n:
        nex = next_arithmetics(lis)
        if nex[0] > mini:
            lis.append(mini)
            mini = mini+1
        else:
            i = 0
            l = len(nex)
            while (i <l-1) and (nex[i+1] == nex[i] + 1):
                i += 1
            if nex[i]+1 <= n:
                lis.append(nex[i]+1)
            mini = nex[i]+2
    return lis
```

```
def is_not_arithmetic (lis):
    n = len(lis)
    cond = True
    l = -1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            for k in range(j):
                if lis[i]-lis[j] == lis[j]- lis[k]:
                    return False, (k,j,i)
    return True
```

The first describes the candidate you should avoid for the next members of your list, the second just gives the answer and the last checks if you don't have 3 consecutive numbers of an arithmetic sequence in you list.

Mathematically, I had some insights like trying to compute the next arithmetic number, or working with projections of affine lines in $\mathbb{N}^2$ but I did not succeed

Here is the graph of len(Szekeres(n)):
[image: graph of len(Szekeres(n))]
And a second one with bigger $n$
[image]

It seems we gat by dezooming a sort of **Cantor's staircase** or devil's staircase I don't know how you call it

Edit: with the property of the basis $3$ is it clearer why it forms a sort of cantor's staircase...

Comment: In fact, it is a known sequence, the Szekeres sequence : https://oeis.org/A003278

Comment: @JeanMarie amazing! Is there a conjecture or a theorem for an equivalent of the length of this sequence?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know this sequence before...

Comment: For some odd reason, when we get $n$ really big, it looks like Cantor's staircase

Comment: I calculate the answer using mod 3 and it is 128 as well, maybe I will post the step later but I have something to do now

Comment: Connection with Cantor's staircase : Not surprizing when you see the OEIS text mentionning the connection with base three representation without two's

Comment: Yes I mentioned it in the bottom

Comment: Please have a look at my (modest) answer.

Comment: [Connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4458703/305862)

Answer (score 2):

$n+1$ is in your sequence iff $n$ base $3$ only has $0$ and $1$’s. The math works out nicer if you include $0$ in your sequence initially and then later shift everything over by $1$.

If a number has any $2$’s in it, you can see it forms a linear sequence by replacing the $2$’s with $0$’s and $1$’s. For example, $1202_3$ is in a linear progression with $1101_3$ and $1000_3$. Similarly, if $x$ and $y$ first differ in base 3 at the $k$th digit, then $2x-y$ has the same last $k-1$ digits and the $k$th digit would be 2 (either $2\cdot 1-0=2$ or $2\cdot0-1=-1$ triggers a carry leading to $3-1=2$), so any term with only $0$ and $1$’s in base 3 can’t be in a linear progression.

$2022_{10}=2202220_3$, so that gives $0_3,1_3,10_3,…,1111111_3$. That’s $0$ or $1$ in 7 positions, so there are $2^7=128$ numbers in your list up to that point.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short way to program the sequence (Matlab) :

```
L=[1;2;4];
for k=5:1094
   b=0; % (1)
   p=1; % (2)
   while (p<length(L)) && (b==0)
      b=ismember((L(p)+k)/2,L);
      p=p+1;
   end;
   if b==0;L=[L;k];end; % (3)
end
plot(L)
```

Explanations :

(1) b : boolean variable remaining false while no A.P. found.

(2) p : browsing index in (the current state of) L.

(3) conditional adding of element k to list L.

The result is a kind of reciprocal of the curve given in the answer by @Jules Besson :

[image]

Comment: Very Nice work !!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Python program:

````
N = 2023

candied = []
noncandied = []
for i in range(1, N+1):
    if i in noncandied:
        continue

    candied.append(i)
    noncandied.extend(i + (i-c) for c in candied)

print(candied)
```
````

Answer (score -1):

The answer I calculate using mod 3 is 128. And here is the ways.
I calculate the number available in 100 and the numbers are 1,2,4,5,10,11,13,14,28,29,31,32,37,38,40,41,82,83,85,86,91,92,94,95,109,110,112,113,118,119,121,122(I don't think it is possible to get further without the help of a computer)

we can observe that the number is in 4 a group

then change the number to base 3

1. 1,2,11,12
2. 101,102,111,112
3. 1001,1002,1011,1012
4. 1101,1102,1111,1112
5. 10001,10002,10011,10012
6. 10101,10102,10111,10112
7. 11001, 11002,11011,11012
8. 11101, 11102,11111,11112

then u just need to observe the pattern and find the answer easily

The largest number will be 1111112 which is 1094

and u can list a total of 128 number